# Converting ReactJS code to ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I recently had to pick up ReactJS in the last few days to work on a project. While I have most of the basics down, I'm coming across issues with the syntax of ES5 and ES6. I can't quite grasp the differences and how to convert code from one to the other. I've been using a lot of copy and paste of ES6, so it's been fairly easy for me to pick up. But when I come across ES5, I struggle.

I'm trying to create a modal from pre-existing code, but I don't quite know what it's supposed to look like in the end. Here is what I'm trying to convert:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Example = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
      return { showModal: false };
   },

    close() {
     this.setState({ showModal: false });
   },

    open() {
     this.setState({ showModal: true });
   },

    render() {
     const popover = (
      <Popover id="modal-popover" title="popover">
    very popover. such engagement
  </Popover>
);
const tooltip = (
  <Tooltip id="modal-tooltip">
    wow.
  </Tooltip>
);

return (
  <div>
    <p>Click to get the full Modal experience!</p>

    <Button
      bsStyle="primary"
      bsSize="large"
      onClick={this.open}
    >
      Launch demo modal
    </Button>

    <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>

        <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
        <p>there is a <OverlayTrigger overlay={popover}><a href="#">popover</a></OverlayTrigger> here</p>

        <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
        <p>there is a <OverlayTrigger overlay={tooltip}><a href="#">tooltip</a></OverlayTrigger> here</p>

        <hr />

        <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  </div>
   );
 }
    });

  ReactDOM.render(<Example />, mountNode);
```

Any tips/tricks/help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're building your js bundle using something like webpack, you can pick and choose what features of es6 you want to use. it isn't "all or nothing." For example, in the above you're using the ES6 import syntax.

also, an important distinction is the difference between es6 features and React.createClass() and React's extends Component structure. You can read about the here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html